# Multiple Audio in Fragments

Tags: android, audio

Being an absolutely novice, could not understand the problem. An app with an activity, two fragments, each fragment contains 15 rows each of which has two TextViews and a Button (to play a audio piece). Launched successfully, I have noticed, if I don't play the audios, it works fine, I can navigate to anywhere, to any fragments, or to the activity back and forth easily but if I play the audios, and then try to move to another fragment or the activity, the app crashes. The activity that launches in the beginning only carries two Buttons to navigate to the fragments. What is wrong with this app? I have added only the first Fragment and some of the rows.. Please suggest..

```
  package com.misty.multiaudioexperiments;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.widget.Button;



    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);




            final Button buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioMenInEnglishVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioMenInEnglishId);
            final Button buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioPencilInEnglishVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioPencilInEnglishId);
            final Button buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioPilotInEnglishVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioPilotInEnglishId);
            final Button buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioRunInEnglishVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioRunInEnglishId);
            final Button buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioShoeInEnglishVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioShoeInEnglishId);



            final Button buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToContentsVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToContentsId);
            final Button buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToNextFragmentVar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToNextFragmentId);





        buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioMenInEnglishVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mp != null) {
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.men);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;




                    }
                });



            }
        });


















        buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioPencilInEnglishVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mp != null) {
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pencil);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;




                    }
                });



            }
        });
















        buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioPilotInEnglishVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mp != null) {
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pilot);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;




                    }
                });



            }
        });















        buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioRunInEnglishVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mp != null) {
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.run);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;




                    }
                });



            }
        });



















        buttonInFragmentOneToPlayAudioShoeInEnglishVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mp != null) {
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shoe);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;




                    }
                });



            }
        });

















        buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToContentsVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;

            }
        });




//THIS BUTTON TAKES TO THE NEXT OR FRAGMENT TWO PAGE STOPPING MEDIAPLAYER IF PLAYING

        buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToNextFragmentVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentTwo());
                ft.commit();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;



            }
        });



        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the logcat of crash?

Comment: I tried to copy the Logcat(Error) messages and paste them here but saying it's long.. How can I add?

Comment: just copy the piece of log related to error , not all of it .

Comment: 2019-12-22 16:55:45.453 9494-9523/com.misty.multiaudioexperiments E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2019-12-22 16:56:06.078 9494-9494/com.misty.multiaudioexperiments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.misty.multiaudioexperiments, PID: 9494
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.reset()' on a null object reference
        at com.misty.multiaudioexperiments.FragmentTwo$16.onClick(FragmentTwo.java:696)

Comment: Could you click on blue highlighted error and tell in your post which line is that error happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because the mp instance is null when you try to exit the fragment.

1. The mp reference is instantiated when you create a new instance of the fragment

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

2. The mp reference is nullified every time you play an audio

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
    }
});
```

**Case 1:**

If you leave the fragment without playing any audio the instance is not altered with, so you do not get any exceptions.

**Case 2:**

If you leave the fragment after playing some audio, the mp instance is set to null, hence when you try to call `mp.reset()` on the null instance, it results in an exception.

**Solution**

Surround the exit check with if block:-

```
if(mp != null){
     mp.reset();
     mp.release();
     mp = null;
}
```

As a best practice do this check, in the `onStop()` method of both the fragments and remove it from the `onClick()`

```
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I added the 'if block' as you asked.. and seems like it did crash as of now. But please show me where and how to use onStop() method. Never used it..

Comment: onStop() is a lifecycle method of the Fragment, so in order to use it in your fragment you just have to override it with @override. So you can just paste this in your Fragment classes:-
```@Override
    public void onStop() {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(null)
            mp = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Comment: Also can you please post the latest stack trace of your logcat?

Comment: Sorry for mistyping. I intended to say: "I added the 'if block' as you asked.. and seems like it did not crash as of now.". It is not crashing although I did not add onStop() method.

Comment: onStop() method I used:                                                                                                                                                                                                               return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

}

Comment: onClick() method, thus:                                                                                                                      
buttonInLessonOneForTransitionToNextLessonVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  @Override   public void onClick(View v) {  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new LessonTwo());
ft.commit();  if(mp != null){  mp.reset();   mp.release();  mp = null;  }   }    });

Comment: onClick() for Audio Play:                                                                                                        buttonInLessonOneToPlayAudioShoeInEnglishVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   public void onClick(View v) {    if(mp != null) {  if(mp.isPlaying()){ onStop();    }   }   mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shoe);   mp.start();     mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {    mp.release();    mp = null;   }  });  }  });

Comment: use the ```onStop()``` method I have mentioned in my comment and get rid of ```if(mp != null){ mp.reset(); mp.release(); mp = null; }``` from both your 
```buttonInLessonOneForTransitionToNextLessonVar``` and ```buttonInFragmentOneForTransitionToContentsVar``` button's ```onClick```